# Regex for UserName

Tags: regex, validation

can you please help me with creating regex having below rules.

1. Starting and Ending of string do not have any special characters
2. Allowed special characters are `@`, `-` and `_` .
3. immediate 2 special characters are not allowed in string (ie `Test..ds`, `Test_@ds`)
4. String can have maximum 4 special characters
5. String can have maximum 4 numbers (0-9)
6. string minimum length is 8 and maximum 50

I tried the regex below, but I don't know how to limit it to four digits.

```
 ^[a-zA-Z0-9]((?!(\.|))|\.(?!(_|\.))|[a-zA-Z0-9]){6,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Examples:

**Valid String:**

1. `User.Name_77`
2. `01User_Name_77`
3. `UserNameTest`
4. `U_ser@Na_m_e`

**Invalid String**

5. `User_Name012345`
6. `User__Name`
7. `User.@Name`
8. `@UserName77`
9. `UserName77@`
10. `U_ser@@Na_me`
11. `U_ser@-Na_me`

Comment: what you have tried so far???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's of the "gimme the codez" variety. Try something, then share with us where you encountered difficulties.

Comment: I agree with @Joseph Silber but i still think you deserve some chance.

You could use this site http://regexpal.com/ it's show you in the first text box to write your own regex expression and on second text block the text you are trying to match.

It does have a quick reference in the right that help you understand things like * match all, {n,n}.

Comment: i did below regex. But 1 thing im unble to do, it should not allow more then 4 number in string.     ^[a-zA-Z0-9](_(?!(\.|_))|\.(?!(_|\.))|[a-zA-Z0-9]){6,18}[a-zA-Z0-9]$

Comment: You should stick that in your original question.

Comment: It would help to post in your question several examples of valid and invalid usernames.

Comment: Will be useful add examples of what do you want

Comment: mmm, what about "U_s_e.r@N.a_m_e", has more than 4 special characters.. ?

Comment: but `U_s_e.r@N.a_m_e` has 7 special characters, which breaks rule 4. Please check your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nice spec; you can almost directly transcribe it into positive and negative look aheads (updated based on comment):

```
^
(?!.*[-@_.]{2})           # no two special in a row
(?!(?:.*[-@_.]){5})       # less than 5 specials
(?!(?:.*\d){5})           # less than 5 digits
(?!^[^a-zA-Z0-9])          # no special at start
(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9]$)         # no specail at end
([-@_.a-zA-Z0-9]{8,50})    #8 to 50 of that char set
$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN6vS9/2)

Comment: hi, please verify below,  ValidString : User_N7447ame

InvalidString: 44User_N77ame44 , User_N74471ame , User_Na_m-e-T-est

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(?!(([A-Za-z0-9]+[\@\.\-\_]){5,}|[A-Za-z0-9]*[\@\.\-\_]{5,}|.{51,}$|.{0,7}$|(.*\d){5,}|.+[\@\.\-\_]{2,}))\b[A-Za-z0-9@._-]*\b$/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/jX3jS4/7

Comment: its not working for below 2 strings.  *U_ser@@Na_me* and *U_ser@-Na_me*

Comment: space should not allowed in string